# Rule in Gmail that adds calendar invites from a particular email address to a different calendar

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I get emails from a particular email address with calendar invites.

These emails automatically creates calendar entries for me in my default calendar. How can I have the calendar invites from this email address be sent to a different calendar on my Gmail account?